# Unexpected behaviour of res.redirect() with different status codes

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, http-status-codes

I have a Node.js app that uses express, mongoose and Passport. At this stage I only have authentication (Google, Facebook and local) and it's all working well. I'm trying to handle errors in a comprehensive way, and am struggling with HTTP status codes. My problem is that I can't seem to be fully in control of the HTTP status codes that my app sends.

This is the code in my Passport local strategy. As you can see, I'm attemtping to throw two errors with different status codes (so that I can easily differentiate them in my test cases).

```
passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(
        { usernameField: 'email' },
        async (email, password, done) => {
            try {
                const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
                if (!user || !user.validPassword(password))
                    throw new UserError(
                        'Wrong email or password.',
                        '/login',
                        302
                    );
                else if (!user.verified)
                    throw new UserError(
                        "This account hasn't been verified. Check your emails.",
                        '/login',
                        304
                    );
                else return done(null, user);
            } catch (e) {
                return done(e);
            }
        }
    )
);
```

The custom error class is defined as follows:

```
class UserError extends Error {
    constructor(msg, redirect, status) {
        super(msg);
        this.name = this.constructor.name;
        this.msg = msg || 'UserError: Auth + User validation.';
        this.redirect = redirect || '/';
        this.status = status || 302;
    }
}
```

And handled by this express middleware:

```
const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err.name == 'UserError') {
        req.flash('error', err.msg);
        res.redirect(err.status, err.redirect);
        // res.redirect(302, err.redirect);
    } else if (err.name == 'ValidationError') {
        if (err.errors.password) {
            req.flash(
                'error',
                'Server error: Password must be at least 6 characters.'
            );
            res.redirect('/');
        }
        if (err.errors.email) {
            req.flash(
                'error',
                'Server error: ' +
                    err.errors.email.value +
                    ' is not a valid email.'
            );
            res.redirect('/');
        }
        // } else if (err.name == 'MongoError') {
        //     res.send(err);
        // } else if (err.name == 'JsonWebTokenError') {
        //     res.send(err);
    } else {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
    }
};
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to generate the errors with a custom HTTP status code (which defaults to 302 if no status code is provided to the UserError() call).

And here are my test cases:

```
it('Wrong credentials -> 304, with redirection to /login', (done) => {
        request
            .post(`${baseUrl}/login/email`)
            .type('form')
            .send({
                email: users[0].email,
                password: users[1].password
            })
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.statusCode).toBe(304);
                expect(res.headers.location).toBe('/login');
                done();
            });
    });
    it('Unverified user -> 304, with redirection to /login', (done) => {
        agent
            .post(`${baseUrl}/login/email`)
            .type('form')
            .send({
                email: users[1].email,
                password: users[1].password
            })
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.statusCode).toBe(304);
                expect(res.headers.location).toBe('/login');
                done();
            });
    });
```

The unexpected behaviour is that the expect calls in my test suites tell me they're receiving very unexpected HTTP status codes:

- If I try to throw the error with status 304 => I get a 304. Everybody's happy.
- Throwing with status 300 => I get 300. So far so good.
- Try to throw with status 301, 302 or 303 => I get a 200.
- Try to throw with status 305, 307 or 307 => I get a 404.

So there's definitely something I'm not understanding correctly, but I don't know if that's HTTP status codes, the correct way to res.redirect(), or the way Passport works... Any hindsight would be welcome on what's happening behind the scenes!